# Android simple client and server. Text doesn't come through

Tags: android, sockets

I'm trying to learn how to send some text from one phone to another.

My Server app is:

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Server extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    Thread serverThread = null;

    private TextView text;



    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);

        updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        this.serverThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                Log.d("Test","Listening");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    socket = serverSocket.accept();

                    CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                    new Thread(commThread).start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket clientSocket;

        private BufferedReader input;

        public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

            try {

                this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void run() {


            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                try {

                    String read = input.readLine();

                    updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }

    }

}
```

And my client app is:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Client extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
    //private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.0.129";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        try {
            EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            String str = et.getText().toString();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I don't get any errors but the text doesn't come through. Both phones are on the same network.

I don't see the mistake.

Comment: Maybe try adding `out.flush();` after `out.println(str);`.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem..

Comment: Do you have `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in manifest? Do you see any exceptions in logcat? Is your server even accepting the client socket? Is traffic from one host to another permitted by your router/access point?

Comment: They have both INTERNET permission. No there are no exceptions. My network is a standard one with no restrictions...

Comment: Sorry, I had some exceptions http://i40.tinypic.com/2e0tkw5.png

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. First the port numbers where different. Had a typo :-). Second my phone always switched his network to another wireless so they were on different wireless networks.

Code works like a charm if you set both portnumbers equal.